# Convert gif with uneven delay to uniform delay between frames

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, gif

I have a gif and one python script, which takes the gif, processes individual frame as per requirement, and reassembles the frames with original frame rate. The problem is when I export a GIF file from my PowerPoint animations, it creates uneven intervals between frames, and the expected output is not achieved.

Here are the visuals of GIF I created using PowerPoint (47 frames showing up at uneven intervals)
[image]

(notice the frame counter here) The GIF, visually, is as I expected, but the frames are not.

Relevant part of my python script:

```py
im = Image.open(file)
im_name = str(im.filename[len(folder) + 1:]).split('.')[0]

x, y, new_w, new_h = get_x_y(im)

im_list = []

for frame in ImageSequence.Iterator(im):

    frame = frame.convert('RGBA').resize((new_w, new_h))
    frame = stroke(frame, threshold=threshold, stroke_size=stroke_size, color=white)
    image = Image.new('RGBA', (square_side, square_side))
    image.paste(frame, (x, y), frame)
    image = gen_frame(image)
    im_list.append(image)

duration = im.info['duration']

img = im_list[0]
imgs = im_list[1:]

img.save(f"{output_folder}/{im.filename}_out.gif", save_all=True, append_images=imgs,
         duration=duration, loop=0, optimize=False, disposal=2, lossless=True)


# stroke(), gen_frame() and get_x_y() are my custom functions, working as expected
# For this particular "smirking doge meme" gif the duration is returned as 210ms
```

Now here are the original and output GIFs:

### Input:

[image]

### Output:

[image]

How can i get a gif with uniform interval from this mess?